# workflow / option to expand other options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a question about a conference quotation form that I am building.
Once the user enters various information such as the conference date, number of delegates etc,  I need other options to appear dependant on the duration of the conference.  ie. If the user inputs dates showing that the conference will last 3 days - then 3 "sections" needs to appear for each day of the conference with inputs regarding meals for that particular day, etc.

What route could I take to accomplish this?

I am struggling to explain - so If i am not clear, please tell me and I will try to explain better

thank you

Comment: how are you entering the dates? a single text field? a select for day month and year? Datepicker?

Comment: i am using a datepicker for the starting date, and ending dates of the conference. I then have a text field which displays  /  calculates the  duration of the conference

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: I really dont know much about javascript at all, and was just hoping to be pointed in the right direction.  I would then try to use it on my own.  I have not really tried anything, as nothing I think of even remotely comes close to achieving this.  thank you for the link @Sam.  I understand where you are coming from .

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you'll find something here: [jquery datepicker difference](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+datepicker+difference)

If you have the difference in days you can simply add a for loop

```
for(var i=0;i<differenceInDays;i++){
    $('#days').append('<input name="day'+i+'"/>');
}
```

Comment: thank you @Thomas.  I am able to display the datepicker difference in a text box..  I found this link http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/10/13/how-to-display-form-fields-based-on-selection-with-or-without-jquery-cookie/  which I think may be in the right direction to display fields dependant on dpicker result?

Comment: ok, so basically, the "for....."  will tell the other fields to appear when for each time that the "day" is increased?     (sorry for the lack of terminology,  I am really a newbie :-)

Comment: My code will add as many input fields as the number of days difference and has to be run each time one of the dates changes. It's not a complete solution since you don't want to add all textfields if there already are some.